# Why does neither the Army, the Camarilla or the Spree use guns?

Tags: motherland-fort-salem

Over the course of *Motherland: Fort Salem*, there are multiple occasions where one side or the other would have fared way better had they used guns. I'm mainly thinking of:

- the season 1 finale, where the Camarilla could have stormed the witches by gunning into the storm, and conversely (the witches knew the remaining Tarim were already evacuated, and therefore only Camarillas would have been hit);
- the season 2 finale, where the witches being (temporarily) deprived of their songs could have kept the Camarilla from entering Fort Salem by holding their lines with rifles;
- as a general thing, a military being trained in guns does not seem absurd.

I could have heard that the Camarilla wanted to stay old-fashioned, like the way they use their traditional curved knife, but their use of technology to mimic and neutralise witches' spell seems to indicate otherwise. I get that they want to harvest witches' vocal cords, so a throat shot would be out of the question (and then again...), but a leg wound may be enough to incapacitate someone while keeping them "harvestable", and is certainly safer than trying to close in for a sword/dagger kill.

As per the Army, versatility on the field cannot be considered a disadvantage, can it? Unless guns somehow mess with spells but I don't think such a thing was hinted at.

Admittedly the Spree are the only ones for whom guns would go against the whole ideology.

Out-of-universe, obviously it's a show about witches and the audience expects to watch supernatural stuff, but is there an in-universe reason for the lack of guns?